# Dynamically Change data in a dropdown menu - FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

I have a horizontal list of Categories; e.g. CARS and below it there is a dropdown menu fetch list of models per every CAR selected in the list. So my issue is after i select eg Toyota and the dropdown menu is filled with models eg - Camry, Vits, Caldina, Hilux, That is fine... but is i select one eg Camry and in the list of CARS i select another CAR eg HONDA.. the UI breaks.. can anyone tell me how i can efficiently reuse the same dropdown and just be changing the arraylist it fetchs from even when one item was selectd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar like this:

For car brand:

```
  int selectedBrandItem;
  int selectedModelItem;
  int selectedByYearItem;
  var listTemp;
Container(
                                width: _size.width,
                                height: _size.height* 0.08,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Theme.greyColor[600]
                                  ),
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:10.0),
                                  child: DropdownButton(
                                    hint: Text(allTranslations.text('brand')),
                                    value: selectedBrandItem,
                                    onChanged: (value){
                                      setState(() {
                                        selectedBrandItem = value;
                                         selectedModelItem = null;
                                        selectedByYearItem = null;
                                        
                                      });
                                    },
                                    items: (state.response.brandList == null || state.response.brandList == [])?listTemp:state.response.brandList.map((e) =>
                                        DropdownMenuItem(
                                            value: e.id,
                                            child: Text(
                                              e.brandName,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Theme.GreyColor,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                  fontSize: 16.0
                                              ),
                                            )
                                        )
                                    ).toList()??[],
                                    isExpanded: true,
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down, color: Theme.greyColor[500],),
                                    underline: Container(color: Colors.transparent,),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
```

For car model:

```
Container(
                                width: _size.width,
                                height: _size.height* 0.08,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Theme.greyColor[600]
                                  ),
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:10.0),
                                  child: DropdownButton(
                                    hint: Text(allTranslations.text('model')),
                                    value: selectedModelItem,
                                    onChanged: (value){
                                      setState(() {
                                        selectedModelItem = value;
                                        selectedByYearItem = null;
                                      
                                      });
                                    },
                                    items: state.response.modelList.map((e) =>
                                        DropdownMenuItem(
                                            value: e.id,
                                            child: Text(
                                              e.modelName,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Theme.GreyColor,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                  fontSize: 16.0
                                              ),
                                            )
                                        )
                                    ).toList()??[],
                                    isExpanded: true,
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down, color: Theme.greyColor[500],),
                                    underline: Container(color: Colors.transparent,),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
```

For car year:

```
Container(
                                width: _size.width,
                                height: _size.height* 0.08,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      color: Theme.greyColor[600]
                                  ),
                                ),
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:10.0),
                                  child: DropdownButton(
                                    hint: Text(allTranslations.text('year')),
                                    value: selectedByYearItem,
                                    onChanged: (value){
                                      setState(() {
                                        selectedByYearItem = value;
                                        
                                      });
                                    },
                                    items: (state.response.yearList == null || state.response.yearList  == [] )?listTemp:state.response.yearList .map((e) =>
                                        DropdownMenuItem(
                                            value: e.id,
                                            child: Text(
                                              e.year,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Theme.GreyColor,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                                  fontSize: 16.0
                                              ),
                                            )
                                        )
                                    ).toList()??[],
                                    isExpanded: true,
                                    icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down, color: Theme.greyColor[500],),
                                    underline: Container(color: Colors.transparent,),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
```